# Why am I getting an error in line 5 for this elif statement?

Tags: python

I have to write a simple program to give assign a letter grade to a test score from 0.0 - 1.0

```
score = input("Enter Score: ")
g = float(score)

if 0.0 <= g <= 1.0:
    elif 0.9 <= g <= 1.0:
        print("A")
    
    elif 0.8 <= g < 0.9:
        print("B")
    
    elif 0.7 <= g < 0.8:
        print("C")
    
    elif 0.6 <= g < 0.7:
        print("D")
    
    elif 0.0 <= g < 0.6:
        print("F")  
else:
    print("Error, given value is out of the 0.0-1.0 range")
    quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

The `if`-`elif` statement on a new block should start with `if`. It can't start with `elif`.

Try it this way:

```
score = input("Enter Score: ")
g = float(score)

if 0.0 <= g <= 1.0:
    if 0.9 <= g <= 1.0:
        print("A")
    
    elif 0.8 <= g < 0.9:
        print("B")
    
    elif 0.7 <= g < 0.8:
        print("C")
    
    elif 0.6 <= g < 0.7:
        print("D")
    
    elif 0.0 <= g < 0.6:
        print("F")  
else:
    print("Error, given value is out of the 0.0-1.0 range")
    quit()
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Im a new python programmer, thank you for showing me i needed to make another if rather than start with an elif immediatley

Comment: You're welcome. If this solved your issue, can you please mark it as an answer?